# Generate same hash from strings in unpredicatable order C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, hash

I get in the input of my function list of strings.
But the order of these strings may be different for each function call.
I want to generate a hash from these strings, but it must be equal for two strings excluding order.
So, the hash of `hello` and `world` must be equal to the hash of `world` and `hello`.
The hash must be secure and resistant to collisions.
How can I do it?

P.S.: I can get a hash from an array of bytes, but not excluding order.

Comment: what are your requirements for this hash? Does it need to be secure? How bothered are you about collisions?

Comment: what about sorting alphabetically the list of string before generating the hash?

Comment: @AlanBirtles, yeah, the hash must be secure, I'm bothered about collisions

Comment: you should edit these requirements into your question especially as it invalidates the 2 answers currently posted

Comment: The question of security/collision is not really relevant. Pick any well known cryptographic hash which operators on a single string. Then to use this hash on your list of strings: first sort the strings (simple way, insert each element into a multiset). Then define an injection from a sorted list of strings (or a multiset) to a single string. One such injection: concatenate the sorted list with a seperator in between each element which will not appear in any string (such as the character `\0', which by definition, does not appear in a string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use any position independent hash either on bytes or use any hash on words and then use position independent hash on word's hashes.

Position independent hash can be any function that has same result when arguments are swapped: +, *, xor, etc.

Comment: Is it secure? What about collisions?

Comment: No, of course it is not secure. Collisions happen in any types of hashes, but of course this type of hash can have more collisions on strings than position dependent hashes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sum of each character for the hash:

```
'h' + 'e' + 'l' + 'l' + 'o' + 'w' + 'o' + 'r' + 'l' + 'd' == 'w' + 'o' + 'r' + 'l' + 'd' + 'h' + 'e' + 'l' + 'l' + 'o'
```